# Django Filter get value from field

Tags: django

How do I get the value from a field after a running filter?

`all_q_answered = ProjectQuestionnaireAnswer.objects.filter(response = q_response, answer__isnull=False)`

I need to get the values of the field `choice_weight` from the returned queryset?

The `ProjectQuestoinnaireAnswer` model has a fk to a `Choices` model that has a choice weight value

```
class ProjectQuestionnaireAnswer(models.Model):
    YN_Choices = [
        ('Yes', 'Yes'),
        ('No', 'No'),
        ('Unknown', 'Unknown')
    ]
    question = models.ForeignKey(ProjectQuestionnaireQuestion, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Choice, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True)
    response = models.ForeignKey(ProjectQuestionnaireResponse, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(ProjectQuestionnaireQuestion, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    choice_value = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    choice_weight = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `values()` method:

```
all_q_answered = ProjectQuestionnaireAnswer.objects.filter(response = q_response, answer__isnull=False).values('answer__choice_weight')
```

It will give something like:

```
<QuerySet [{'choice_weight': 'first_choice'}, {'choice_weight': 'second_choice'}]>
```

Comment: I've tried that already. But because Choice_weight is not a field within `ProjectQuestionnaireAnswer` it doesn't work

Comment: My bad, didn't notice. Change it to `answer__choice_weight`. (double underscore)

Answer (score 0):

```
all_q_answered = ProjectQuestionnaireAnswer.objects.filter(response = q_response, answer__isnull=False).values('answer__choice_weight')
```

You can use `__` to get the values of related objescts.

Comment: Good approach, but he needs `Choice` model, so it is going to be `answer__choice_weight`.